# Can't create image2D with r8 layout in compute shader

Tags: opengl-es, compute-shader

I would like to work with grayscale texture in compute shader. For `rgba8` it works fine, but when I declare

```
layout(binding=1, r8) uniform mediump writeonly image2D resultImage;
```

it produces the following error:

```
0:25: S0059: Expected layout qualifier identifier, got 'r8'
```

Is `r8` not allowed for images or is it my platform that does not support `r8`?

Comment: Which OpenGL ES version are you targeting?

Comment: @genpfault 3.2 ES

Comment: What platform/GPU are you using?

Comment: @solidpixel android 7.0, galaxy s7, gpu mali T-880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `r8` isn't a valid image format in OpenGL ES 3.x.

See section 4.4.7 in the specification here:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.pdf

.. for the supported formats.